# Web Api, I need to use different configuration options for CosmosDB between local debugging and dev environment on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am using environment variables in Azure App Service in my ASP.NET Web API.  I am able to read them successfully when the API is deployed to the Azure App service, however that kills my local debugging when I run the project because locally I am reading from appsettings.json (Also appsettings.json is used by the api when I push to our azure dev environment app service)

**I am trying to not have the cosmos url and the cosmos key visible in appsetting.json, and I'm also trying to pull from the app service configuration environment variables because this app will be pushed to a dev repo and a pipeline will move it to an appservice in test, then prod, so I'm trying to have one set of logic that will simply read the environment variables in the app service for the particular url I hit(dev,test,prod etc...)**

If you look at the image below of the configuration in app service I can read cosmos_key and cosmos_url in startup cs.  However to run locally I have to comment out this code from startup.cs that uses the account and key variables that obtain the value from Environment.GetEnvironment.....

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks for your time.

```
private static async Task<LogDBService> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsyncLogs(IConfigurationSection configurationSection)
    {
      
        var databaseName = configurationSection["DatabaseName"];
        var containerName = configurationSection["logContainerName"];
        
        var account = configurationSection["Account"]; 
        
        //var account = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cosmos_uri");
         var key = configurationSection["Key"];  
        //var key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cosmos_key");
        var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient(account, key);
        var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
        await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/matchId");
        var cosmosDbService = new LogDBService(client, databaseName, containerName);            
        return cosmosDbService;
    }
```

[image: Azure App Service]

Appsettings.json
[image]

Appsettings.Development.json
[image]

**startup.cs**

```
    using ODSApiCore.Auth;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
    using ODSApi.BusinessServices;
    using ODSDatabase.DBServices;
    using ODSApi.Extensions;
    using ODSApi.Middleware;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Unos.Foundation;
    using System;
    
    namespace ODSApi
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            private IConfiguration Configuration;
            
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = Requires.NotNull(configuration,nameof(configuration));
            }
            
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddControllers();           
               
                services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ODSApi", Version = "v1" });
                });
    
                //Add unos auth services
                services.AddApigeeJwtBearerAuthentication(Configuration).AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
    
                    options.AddPolicy(PredictiveAnalyticsAuthorizationPolicy.Name, PredictiveAnalyticsAuthorizationPolicy.Policy);
    
                });
                          
               
                    services.AddSingleton<ILogDBService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsyncLogs(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
                    services.AddSingleton<ITimeToNextOfferDBService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsy

ncTimeToNextOffer(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
                services.AddSingleton<IMatchRunDBService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsyncMatchRun(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
                services.AddSingleton<IMortalitySlopeDBService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsyncMortalitySlope(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
                services.AddSingleton<IGraphParamsDBService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsyncGraphParams(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
                services.AddScoped<IMatchRunBusinessService, MatchRunBusinessService>();
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
                services.ConfigureCors();     


        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ODSApi v1"));

            }
            if (env.IsStaging())
            {

            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ODSApi v1"));
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
           

            //Use this Middleware prior to app.UseEndpoints....

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ExceptionHandlingMiddleware));
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });


        }
        /*********************************
         * These are the database services
         * that are injected into the ioc
         * container.  There are 5 Services
         * Based on the 5 collections in ODS
         * The partition key in Cosmos is /matchId
         * except for the graph params table.  The
         * partition key in ODS must be a field in
         * database.
         * ******************************/
        
        private static async Task<LogDBService> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsyncLogs(IConfigurationSection configurationSection)
        {
          
            var databaseName = configurationSection["DatabaseName"];
            var containerName = configurationSection["logContainerName"];
            
            var account = configurationSection["Account"]; 
            
            //var account = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cosmos_uri");
             var key = configurationSection["Key"];  
            //var key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cosmos_key");
            var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient(account, key);
            var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
            await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/matchId");
            var cosmosDbService = new LogDBService(client, databaseName, containerName);            
            return cosmosDbService;
        }
        private static async Task<TimeToNextOfferDBService> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsyncTimeToNextOffer(IConfigurationSection configurationSection)
        {
            var databaseName = configurationSection["DatabaseName"];
            var containerName = configurationSection["ttnoContainerName"];
            var account = configurationSection["Account"];
            var key = configurationSection["Key"];

            var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient(account, key);
            var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
            await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/matchId");

            var cosmosDbService = new TimeToNextOfferDBService(client, databaseName, containerName);
            return cosmosDbService;
        }
        private static async Task<IMatchRunDBService> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsyncMatchRun(IConfigurationSection configurationSection)
        {
            var databaseName = configurationSection["DatabaseName"];
            var containerName = configurationSection["passThroughContainerName"];
            var account = configurationSection["Account"];
            var key = configurationSection["Key"];

            var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient(account, key);
            var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
            await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/matchId");

            var cosmosDBService = new MatchRunDBService(client, databaseName, containerName);

            return cosmosDBService;
        }
        private static async Task<IMortalitySlopeDBService> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsyncMortalitySlope(IConfigurationSection configurationSection)
        {
            var databaseName = configurationSection["DatabaseName"];
            var containerName = configurationSection["mortalitySlopeContainerName"];
            var account = configurationSection["Account"];
            var key = configurationSection["Key"];

            var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient(account, key);
            var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
            await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/matchId");

            var cosmosDbService = new MortalitySlopeDBService(client, databaseName, containerName);
            return cosmosDbService;
        }
        private static async Task<IGraphParamsDBService> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsyncGraphParams(IConfigurationSection configurationSection)
        {
            var databaseName = configurationSection["DatabaseName"];
            var containerName = configurationSection["graphParamsContainerName"];
            var account = configurationSection["Account"];
            var key = configurationSection["Key"];

            var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient(account, key);
            var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
            await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/id");

            var cosmosDbService = new GraphParamsDBService(client, databaseName, containerName);
            return cosmosDbService;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could consider getting the Environment variable (Development or Production) first, then use an if else statement to base on the environment to get the configuration value, Reference [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thanks Zhi, at first pass this is working.  if(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT") == "DEV")
            {
                 account = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cosmos_uri");
                 key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cosmos_key");
            }
          
            else
            {
                 account = configurationSection["Account"];
                 key = configurationSection["Key"];
            }